# how to make the cloudmonkey output plain text with no style info?

Tags: shell, apache-cloudstack

I wander if there's a way to make the cloudmonkey output plain text instead of the ones with the style info so I can filter the output info with ease.

e.g. When I do 'cloudmonkey list users' instead of the 'count = 1 ...' output I got '^[[?1034h^[[32;01mcount ^[[39;49;00m^[[36m=^[[39;49;00m^[[39;49;00m ^[[39;49;00m^[[34;01m1^[[39;49;00m ...', so the filtering job could be a little harder to do, is there's a way to weed out these additional info, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that do the following command could weed out the style info of the output

```
cloudmonkey set color false
```